# CountVectorizer test data loss?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

I am working on a small project that requires using different classification models on BoW data.
I understand that the train and test data must be different to get the model's true accuracy.

For model.score() to work correctly, I need to give it test data and labels in the same dimensions as the initial data. But the test data is in different dimensions, so I do it like this:

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
traindata_bow = vectorizer.fit_transform(traindata)
testdata_bow = vectorizer.transform(testdata)
```

Now, the test data has the same dimensions as the initial train data.

Now on to my question: 
Test data has its own set of dimensions/"characteristics". 
**So by transforming it using the vectorizer are we not losing any of the test data's characteristics?**
I am asking because my model's accuracy ends up being in the 99.9% range and I worry something gets calculated incorrectly (Though my dataset is quite easy)

For example, after the code above:

```
traindata_bow.shape is (35918, 34319) and
testdata_bow.shape  is (8980, 34319)
```

But if I run:

```
testdata_bow = vectorizer.fit_transform(testdata) i get
testdata_bow.shape  is (8980, 20806)
```

So is there any data loss (or even partial merging with the train data) in the transform stage?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Take a quick tour of the tags, [tag:machine-learning] is intended for implementation questions, "*General questions about machine learning (concepts, theory, methodology, terminology etc) should be posted to their specific communities*" such as Stats StackExchange or DataScience.

Comment: But briefly: the answer to your question is "Yes." However: just about every portion of the bag of words model could be considered "*lossy*." It removes word order and rules of grammar, and instead relies on counts.

Comment: Here's another way to think about it: Consider a word that appears in the test data, but not the training data. Even if you knew about that word at training time, the count would still be 0, so it could not affect the results.

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes Hello, thanks a lot for the quick answer! I think I understand your explanation, the counter should indeed be zero!  I am going to take a second look on the docs to try figure out why my accuracy is so high. Sorry for the wrong ML tag and thanks for the kind explanation. (Should I try to remove it?)